# Product of two binary numbers produce a string of 1

Tags: arithmetic, binary

If
$$
x_i = 2^n + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} x_j 2^j \;\; i \in {1,2},
$$

Is there an easy way that maybe I'm not aware of to find the number (just the number) of solutions such that

$$
x_1 x_2 =2^{2n+1}-2^{n-1}
$$

?

I've tried to decompose the numbers $x_1,x_2$ using the binary representation, but It's too confusing to work out the solution, so I don't think that's the way.

Comment: n is fixed, yes, however I don't think it's just $2^k(2^m - 1)$, if you try the multiplication of the numbers $10101 \times 1100$ does the same thing. Or $00001111 \times 00010001$

Comment: The number 1...10...0 with m 0's and n 1's is equal to 2^m(2^n-1), so the number of solutions will be the number of divisors of that number.  If the prime factorization of that number is $p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_t^{e_t}$ then the number of divisors will be $(e_1+1)(e_2+1)\cdots(e_t+1)$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understood, if $ab = 2^m (2^n - 1)$ I factorize and I have $ab = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \ldots p_t^{e_t}$ this means that both $a$ and $b$ can be built using product of such prime factors, is that right?

Comment: Yeah, if I understand the question you're only asking how many ways there are to factor that number, which can be calculated with that formula.

Comment: Is there a simple rule to decompose factor like $2^n - 1$? assuming $n$ is even I could do $(2^n - 1) = (2^{\frac{n}{2}} - 1)(2^{\frac{n}{2}} + 1)$. If $\frac{n}{2}$ is also even I can re-iterate until I reach $\frac{n}{2^k}$ odd, for some $k$ it could exist, so assuming $n$ is odd how $2^n - 1$ can be written?

Comment: There probably won't be a nice universal answer.  Sometimes it factors into fairly small numbers and sometimes it's a prime itself.

Comment: Last question, does the method apply when the product is fractional? like $1.11110000$ how many factors does this have?

Comment: I mean is it possible to use the same technique to workout how many factor $a,b \in [1,2)$ are there to decompose the number $1.11110000$

Comment: There would always be an infinite number in that case because if you had one pair a,b then any other pair a*r, b/r would work too for any number (not necessarily integer) r close enough to 1 to not knock a and b outside the bounds.

Comment: Hi, forget about the fractional number, does it change anything if my product is constrained the value I specified now? Can I at least give a bound using the prime number factorization?